# Get the Trim Area of a PDF with PDF.js?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, trim, pdf.js

I'm playing about with PDF.js, and can't seem to find a solution to my problem.

I have a PDF with a trim area and bleed, I need to get the trim area so that I can crop the PDF image data in HTML canvas.

I see that Acrobat has javascript that can return the Trim based on getPageBox("Trim"). Is there any equivalent in PDF.js? 
I cant seem to find a reference when inspecting the Javascript PDF Object in the console.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get it after editing `pdf.worker.js`. Tested with 1.7.225. First, Add `get trimBox()`  after `get cropBox()` like this:

```
 get trimBox() {
  var trimBox = this.getInheritedPageProp('TrimBox', true);
  if (!isArray(trimBox) || trimBox.length !== 4) {
   return shadow(this, 'trimBox', this.mediaBox);
  }
  return shadow(this, 'trimBox', trimBox);
 },
```

Now, in `handler.on('GetPage', function ...` of `WorkerMessageHandler`, add a few lines like this:

```
 handler.on('GetPage', function wphSetupGetPage(data) {
  return pdfManager.getPage(data.pageIndex).then(function (page) {
   var rotatePromise = pdfManager.ensure(page, 'rotate');
   var refPromise = pdfManager.ensure(page, 'ref');
   var userUnitPromise = pdfManager.ensure(page, 'userUnit');
   var viewPromise = pdfManager.ensure(page, 'view');
   var trimBoxPromise = pdfManager.ensure(page, 'trimBox');  //added
   return Promise.all([
    rotatePromise,
    refPromise,
    userUnitPromise,
    viewPromise,
    trimBoxPromise  //added
   ]).then(function (results) {
    return {
     rotate: results[0],
     ref: results[1],
     userUnit: results[2],
     view: results[3],
     trimBox: results[4]  //added
```

That's it. Now you can get the trim box in your app by `page.pageInfo.trimBox`.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the excellent answer from @Sangbok Lee, 
If you use the latest PDF.js version, the this.getInheritedPageProp function has changed to 

`this._getInheritableProperty('TrimBox', true)`

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.
For anyone else who may be interested in pdf.worker.js on line 2654 I added the following that exposed the trimBox.

```
tboxX = this.pageDict.map.TrimBox[0];
tboxY = this.pageDict.map.TrimBox[1];
tboxW = this.pageDict.map.TrimBox[2];
tboxH = this.pageDict.map.TrimBox[3];
```

I'm sure there is a neater way, but it works.